# Passing a block to .try()

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

This question is about using the .try() method in rails 3 (& a bit about best practice in testing for nil also)

If I have a db object that may or may not be nil, and it has a field which is eg a delimited string, separated by commas and an optional semi-colon, and I want to see if this string contains a particular sub-string, then I might do this:

```
user_page = UserPage.find(id)
if user_page != nil
    result = user_page.pagelist.gsub('\;', ',').split(",").include?(sub)
end
```

So, eg user_page.pagelist == "item_a,item_b;item_c"

I want to re-write this using .try, but cannot find a way of applying the stuff after pagelist

So I have tried passing a block (from this link http://apidock.com/rails/Object/try)

```
user_page.try(:pagelist) {|t| t.gsub('\;', ',').split(",").include?(sub)}
```

However, the block is simply ignored and the returned result is simply pagelist

I have tried other combinations of trying to apply the gsub etc part, but to no avail

How can I apply other methods to the method being 'tried'?

(I dont even know how to phrase the question in an intelligible way!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're probably coming at this wrong - the quick solution should be to add a method to your model:

```
def formatted_pagelist
  (pagelist || "").split(/[;,]/)
end
```

Then you can use it where ever:

```
user_page.formatted_pagelist.include? sub
```

Strictly speaking, I'd say this goes into a decorator. If you're not using a decorator pattern in your app (look into [draper](https://github.com/drapergem/draper)!), then a model method should work fine.

Comment: Updated it to make sure it always returns an array. :)

Comment: that said... what IS the correct syntax for what I was trying to do with the .try() method, in case I want to use it in a different context elsewhere?

Comment: The problem you had is that try doesn't fail on nil values, it fails on missing messages. Since `#pagelist` is always a valid method, it always runs it, sometimes gets a nil back, and passes it to the block. Your block could be amended to `t && t.split(/[;,]).include?(sub)`, though that's starting to get hairy.